# SQL Update Table By Joining Same Table

Tags: sql-server

I am working on an MS Access DB rewrite project that we are converting to a 2005 SQL server back-end/Winform front-end.  I have a query in Access that I need to convert to run in SQL server. Here is the Access query:

```
UPDATE DISTINCTROW VAR, CancelsinTrans 
INNER JOIN Trans ON (CancelsinTrans.ACCT = Trans.ACCT) AND (CancelsinTrans.ITEM_ID = Trans.ITEM_ID) 
SET Trans.TRAN_CD = "1", Trans.LastUpdated = Date() 
WHERE (((Trans.TRAN_CD)<>"1" Or (Trans.TRAN_CD) Is Null) AND 
((CancelsinTrans.TRAN_DT)<[VAR]![Import1]) AND 
((Trans.TRAN_DT)<[VAR]![Import1]));
```

The CancelsinTrans is a query that is pulling accounts from the Trans table - so basically it is joining on itself and performing an update.

Here is the CancelsInTrans query:

```
SELECT Trans.ACCT, Trans.TRAN_TYPE_CD, Trans.TRAN_SUBOR_CD, Trans.M_SRCE_CD, Trans.TRAN_RQST_CD, Trans.TRAN_AM, Trans.TRAN_DR_CR_CD, Trans.TRAN_CXL_CD, Trans.ACCTG_CD, Trans.ITEM_ID, Trans.TRAN_DT, Trans.TRAN_EXEC_TM, Trans.TRAN_QY, Trans.TRAN_NET, Trans.TRAN_EXEC_PR, Trans.M_SECURITY_NR, Trans.M_ORF_OR_ORDRNO, Trans.M_SEQ_NBR, Trans.TRAN_SETTL, Trans.M_ORDER_TAKER_ID, Trans.QUOTR_SEC, Trans.PROD_CD, Trans.SEC_CD, Trans.TRAN_EXEC_DT
FROM Trans
WHERE (((Trans.TRAN_TYPE_CD)="TR") AND ((Trans.TRAN_SUBOR_CD)="TR") AND ((Trans.TRAN_CD)="1") AND ((Trans.ACCTG_CD)="1"));
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to write this query.  I was going to use a stored proc to run this update but should I use a table-function to get the set of records.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server equivalent would be something like the following:

```
Update Trans
Set TRAN_CD = '1'
    , LastUpdated = GETDATE()
Where ( Trans.TRAN_CD <> '1' Or Trans.TRAN_CD Is Null )
    And Trans.TRAN_DT < 'some var value'
    And Exists  (
                Select 1
                From CancelsinTrans As C1
                Where C1.ACCT= Trans.ACCT
                    And C1.ITEM_ID = Trans.ITEM_ID
                    And C1.TRAN_DT < 'some var value'
                )
```

In this case, through your parameterized query, you would replace `some var value` with the value from `[VAR]![Import1]` which I presume was a form value.

**UPDATE**

Given that the CancelsInTran query encapsulates the Trans table, you can eliminate the join like so:

```
Update Trans
Set TRAN_CD = '1'
    , LastUpdated = GetDate()
Where TRAN_TYPE_CD = 'TR'
    And TRAN_SUBOR_CD = 'TR'
    And ACCTG_CD = '1'
    And ( TRAN_CD <> '1' Or TRAN_CD Is Null )
    And TRAN_DT < 'some value'
```

Comment: I am actually trying to remove the subquery if possible. And have all of the code to one stored procedure.

Comment: @bluefeet - How does removing the subquery related to having the code in a single stored procedure? The above is the ANSI way to approach an Update statement.

Comment: The CancelsInTrans is currently an MS Access query that we are going to be removing and replacing with a SQL stored procedure. This query is only used once to perform this update so it seems like a waste to have a separate call to it.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me, but it sounds like you might want CancelIsInTrans to be a view rather than a stored procedure. In circumstances like this, working with a view would probably be easier and could even be more efficient.

Comment: @bluefeet - Ah. You did not tell us that CancelsInTran is a query that encapsulates the Tran table. If that is the case, then you should be able to eliminate the join completely.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working properly.  The CancelsinTrans query is identifying accounts that are already flagged with the TRAN_CD = 1 and basically we want only the remaining accounts that need to be flagged.  The actual query from yesterday should only be updating 428 records but the example above pulls 12491 records.  I am able to identify the records that I need to update but I cannot perform an update with a select distinct present in SQL.

Comment: @bluefeet - To solve your problem you need to produce a Select statement that does not use Distinct nor uses your CancelsInTran query. Remember that when you do an update, it will expand the Distinct to all rows that meet the criteria. In my updated solution, I incorporated the criteria from CancelsInTran but changed the `TRAN_CD` criteria to exclude those set to 1.